# Multiple plots in one figure in a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I am trying to save 10 plots in PNG format, but it only shows me one plot. How can I fix the code below?

```
par(mfrow = c(3,4))
png(filename = "roc.png", width = 1200, height = 1200)
roc = list()
for(id in 1:10)
{
  roc[[id]] = ModelCross[[id]]$roc
  roc_ = ModelCross[[id]]$roc
  coords_<- coords(roc_, best.method="closest.topleft") ## "youden", "closest.topleft"
  par(pty = "s")
  plot(roc_,col = "blue",print.thres="best", print.thres.best.method="closest.topleft")
  print(paste0('roc',id))

}
dev.off()
```

Comment: To show all 10, move the `par(mfrow-c(3,4))` statement to right below `png(...)`.  Calling `png()` invokes a new device basically resetting the `par()` parameters for that device.  Any modifications to `par()` have to be called after the new device is invoked.

Comment: thnaks. the quality of picture is not good. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: "The quality of the picture is not good" is a bit vague but try changing the height and width until it looks good